# VS Code is not recognising Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Following error i am getting when try to create Virtual environment in VS Code

> PS C:\Users\dell\Documents\Programming> python -m venv C:\Users\dell\Documents\Programming\venv
> spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
> python -m venv C:\Users\dell\Documents\Programming\venv
>
> - 
>
> CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> PS C:\Users\dell\Documents\Programming> python3 -m venv C:\Users\dell\Documents\Programming\venv
> e App Execution Aliases.
> PS C:\Users\dell\Documents\Programming> python3 -m venv C:\Users\dell\Documents\Programming\venv
> python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
> spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1
> python3 -m venv C:\Users\dell\Documents\Programming\venv
>
> - 
>
> CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> PS C:\Users\dell\Documents\Programming> python3 -m venv C:\Users\dell\Documents\Programming\venv
> Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Managge App Execution Aliases.

I have turned off python & python 3 on App Execution Aliases as well but it doesnt work

Comment: Show the error interface when you use the command.

Comment: Just wondering, but is python set as system variable? I got this error as well because python was not set on 'PATH' variable. What happens if you open a cmd prompt outside vs-code and type in 'python'? Normally python should be launched inside the cmd prompt then.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error message, there may be an error with your command, which requires more information to solve the problem.

Another option is to create a virtual environment using the command palette.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> **Python: Create Environment**

[image]

Then choose according to your needs.

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_using-the-create-environment-command*